# Why is rock music used for background music when the coach met the principal after a disppointing board meeting?

Tags: analysis, soundtrack, coach-carter

In ***Coach Carter***, why is rock played as the background music when the coach met the principal after a disppointing board meeting?

[image]

The situation is serious, but the background music is rock, which is not the type of music normally I would expect in such a scene. Why so?